# MS Access run time error 438 on load event

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to display logo on MS Access report header. I am using table with the name of Portfolio with contain my ID, Logo fields. After upload image in this table now on report header I added the Image unbounded frame with the name of AutoImage. Now then on load event of report when i call this function it give me error.

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
Me.AutoImage.Picture = DLookup("[Logo]", "Portfolio", "[ID]=1")

End Sub
```

The erro is:

`MS Access run time  error 438  Object does not support this property or method.`

Comment: Are you using Image control? I was able to get code to work.

Comment: yes.... I am using image control but i want to display image with on-load event from other table(portfolio) witch contain logo image

Comment: I tried png and bmt both type of image but don't know whats the problem in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks its working now. I was using image Object Frame. This was my mistake, i just replaced Object frame with Image. Now it working.